# PHP username already exists, when it doesn't

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I've checked many threads about my problem, but it still won't work.

When I enter username, which doesn't exist, it will throw the username has been created yet. But, when I enter an username already registered in my db, it still register.

Here is my php/html page for register :

```
$error = false;
if(isset($_POST['signup'])) {

$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['name']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']);
$cpassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['cpassword']);

$sql = "SELECT name FROM users WHERE name='".mysql_real_escape_string($name)."'";
$query = mysqli_query($sql);
if(mysql_num_rows($query)){
    $error = true;
    $ckname_error = "Nom d'utilisateur déjà enregistré!";
} else { unset($ckname_error); }


if (!$error) {
        if(mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO users(name,mail,password,rank) VALUES('" . $name . "', '" . $email . "', '" . md5($password) . "', 'user' )")) {
            $successmsg = "Successfully Registered! <a href='login.php'>Click here to Login</a>";
            header("Location: login.php");
        } else {
            $errormsg = "Error in registering...Please try again later!";
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is bad. Use pdO

Comment: You are mixing `mysql` and `mysqli`

Comment: Totally agree with Aleksandar. Use PDO.

Comment: Hugo, replace the escape function in your first `$sql = ` line with just `$name` (it's already escaped from before!).   You said the same username gets registered. Do you mean that the db contains multiple records with the same name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting unreliable results because you're mixing `mysqli_` with `mysql_` functions.

**1.** Change:

```
$sql = "SELECT name FROM users WHERE name='".mysql_real_escape_string($name)."'";
```

to:

```
$sql = "SELECT name FROM users WHERE name='$name'";
```

**2.** Change

```
$query = mysqli_query($sql);
```

to:

```
$query = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
```

**3.** Change

```
if(mysql_num_rows($query))
```

to:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($query))
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed `$con`, and use `mysqli_num_rows` not `mysql_num_rows`

```
$query = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($query)){
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using mysqli_query($sql). You should have used 'mysqli_num_rows()' instead of mysql_num_rows().
[PHP reference - mysqli_num_row](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php)

int mysql_num_rows ( resource $result ) expects resource type, whereas if you're using mysqli_query, you should have used int mysqli_num_rows ( mysqli_result $result ) - expects mysqli_results.

Let us know if it works.